# Posson and Binomic distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Exercise:
An ecologist wants to examine the deer population in two different areas, area 1 and area 2. He assumes the number of deer, X and Y, in areas 1 and 2, has Poisson distribution.

> a.
>
> The ecologist calculates that the expected number of deer is $2$ in area $1$ and $4$ in area $2$. Find $P(X=2)$ and $P(X>=3)$, and find an approximate expression for $P(X = Y)$. Specify the expectation you must use to calculate $P(x = y)$.

I have solved this exercise as written below:

Definition:

A random variable $X$ is said to have Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda (>0)$ if $p(x)$ of $X$ is given by

\begin{align}\\
& p(x; \lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}{\lambda ^x}}{x!}
\end{align}

For $\lambda_1 = 2$:

\begin{align}\\
& P(X=2)=\frac{e^{-2}{2^2}}{2!}=\frac{2}{e^2}=0,27067\\
& P(X=1)=\frac{e^{-2}{2^1}}{1!}=\frac{2}{e^2}=0,27067\\
& P(X=0)=\frac{e^{-2}{2^0}}{0!}=\frac{1}{e^2}=0,13533\\
\end{align}

For $P(X>=3)$:
\begin{align}\\
& P(X>=3) = 1-P(X<=2) \\
& P(X>=3) = 1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2) \\
& P(X>=3) = 1-0,27067-0,27067-0,13533 \\
& P(X>=3) = 0,32333
\end{align}

I assume this is correct, but please correct me if I got anything wrong.

> b.
>
> If a deer is in such an area, the ecologist assumes a probability of 0.4, that it will be observed. If there are actually 5 deer in the area, what is the probability that three of them will be observed? What is the expected number of deer observed?

I assume this is a Binominal distibution, because it satisfies the four axioms. There are two possible outcomes; observed or not observed. And $P(1)=0,4$. But I don't know how to continue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are right that b) case is Binominal. The probability to meet deer number 1 is 0,4, the probability to meet deers 1 and 2 at the same time is 0,4*0,4 (events are independent). To meet deers 1, 2 and 3 is 0,4*0,4*0,4. But , because the  deers which are met is not specified, you have to count all option of choosing 3 deers out of 5 - there are $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ such options.

Comment: What you've done in part a looks right to me, though I didn't check the arithmetic, but you don't seem to have addressed the part about $\Pr(X=Y)$.  Did you want to make another question about that?

Comment: In the assignment they specify that I only need to focus on area 1 and X. I think they added the two areas to confuse us and see if we can gather the right information from the given text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom 53=10$ ways to choose the $3$ deer that will be observed.  The probability that they will be observed is $.4^3$ and the probability that the other $2$ will not be seen is $.6^2$  Therefore, the probability is $$10\left(\frac25\right)^3\left(\frac35\right)^2$$